# Owl-carousel configuration

Tags: javascript, image, configuration, owl-carousel

I have an owl-carousel that manages the opening of a modal when clicking on the image to show it enlarged.

the problem is that, it doesn't open the clicked image, but the last previously displayed browsing the carousel, or if it is the first opening of the page, the first image of the carousel.

what is the function that handles this in the config file? or is there a js script that I can add to intervene on the click?

thank you